# When an OS X app is launched by a registered URL scheme, how do you access the full URL?

Tags: macos, cocoa, url, url-scheme, launch-services

I'm working on an Cocoa app which is launched/activated using URLs with a custom scheme which is registered in the Info.plist file like so:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>Open myscheme:// URLs</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myscheme</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

My question is, once the app is launched or  activated, how do I tell what the URL was that launched the app? On iOS, this is easy with the -application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method on the UIApplicationDelegate since it is passed an NSURL instance.

I want to be able to pass in data into my app with URLs like **myscheme://do/something/awesome**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your app delegate's `-applicationWillFinishLaunching:`, do:

```
[[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleAppleEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

And `handleAppleEvent:withReplyEvent:` should look something like:

```
- (void)handleAppleEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent {
    NSString *urlString = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    // do something with the URL string
}
```

Comment: What is keyDirectObject and where is it defined?  I don't understand what the value of keyDirectObject is supposed to be.  Thanks.

Comment: For those that are wondering like me, "How does keyDirectObject compile without syntax error for a missing symbol?", it's defined in AE/AppleEvents.h as an enum case.  Somehow AE/AppleEvents.h gets included in your app even if you don't directly include it.