# Drag a link onto OSX app dock icon

Tags: macos, dock

When I use safari, i can drag the url onto the desktop to save this webpage as a .webloc file.
I also can drag the url from safari onto Chrome app, the Chrome app will open this link.
But when i try to drag the url onto my own app, nothing happens, my app won't go into

```
- (void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames
```

How to do this? Chrome works perfectly so i'm quite sure there is way to handle this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specific to OS X and Apple. It probably should be on https://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It's a programming question, it's not off-topic.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731601/when-an-os-x-app-is-launched-by-a-registered-url-scheme-how-do-you-access-the-f?rq=1).