# Load link in NSTextField in a WKWebView

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, wkwebview

I have an NSAttributedString which has multiple links (with NSLinkAttributeName) in it. Clicking on the link, launches the web browser, and loads the page. Instead, I would like to intercept it and show the link in a webview in my application itself. Is there an easy way to do this (outside of subclassing NSTextField and implementing a custom mouseDown: - which might make me lose other functionality like selection etc.)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sure doesn't look like they make it obvious how to map it directly to a different command.  One roundabout idea would be to register a custom URL handler when you start the app for a unique URL scheme (e.g. `http_myapp_internal://`, and use that custom URL scheme in your link). I would hope there's an easier way, but this should work.

The following SO question seems to illustrate how to implement this idea:

[When an OS X app is launched by a registered URL scheme, how do you access the full URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731601/when-an-os-x-app-is-launched-by-a-registered-url-scheme-how-do-you-access-the-f)